# Update a nested state array based on selected value

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to update which menu item was clicked and therefore change the class accordingly. I have tried different way suggested to do it but couldn't make it work.

Heres my code:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            menuState: [
                {
                    menuName: 'homeMenuStatus',
                    homeMenuStatus: 'inactive',
                    ulSidenavClass: "nav child_menu no-display"
                },
                {
                    menuName: 'accountMenuStatus',
                    accountMenuStatus: 'active',
                    ulSidenavClass: "nav child_menu block-display"
                },
                {
                    menuName: 'contactMenuStatus',
                    peopleMenuStatus: 'inactive',
                    ulSidenavClass: "nav child_menu no-display"
                },

            ]
        }
    }

handleClick(menuClicked) {
        this.state.menuState.map((name, index) => {
            let thisMenu = name.menuName;

            if(name.menuName == menuClicked) {
                if(this.state.menuClicked === 'active') {
                    this.setState({
                        ...this.state,
                        menuClicked: 'inactive',
                        ulSidenavClass: 'block-display height-adjust'
                    });
                } else {
                    this.setState({
                        ...this.state,
                        menuClicked: 'active',
                        ulSidenavClass: 'block-display'
                    });
                }
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    ...this.state,
                    thisMenu: 'inactive',
                    ulSidenavClass: 'block-display height-adjust'
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li className={this.state.menuState[0].homeMenuStatus}>
                <a onClick={() => this.handleClick('homeMenuStatus')}>Home </a>
                <ul className={this.state.menuState[0].ulSidenavClass}>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Activities</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

My state object is not getting changed. Must be doing something wrong in setState(). Can anyone please guide me.

Comment: In the state, you haven't written menuClicked, thisMenu and ulSIdenavClass. you need to write them too when you are initializing state.

Comment: menuClicked is the name of the menu. I passed it as a param of handleClick(menuClicked). it will replace like this.setState({
                    ...this.state,
    "homeMenuStatus" =>    menuClicked: 'active',
                    ulSidenavClass: 'block-display'
                });

Comment: ok. I get it. But where are you getting the old state? I guess you have to pass previous State too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly updating the state, use prevState syntax and return the mapped updated values like

```
handleClick(menuClicked) {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({menuState: prevState.menuState.map((name, index) => {
           if(name.menuName === menuClicked) {
              if(name.menuClicked === 'active') {
                  return {
                      ...name,
                      menuClicked: 'inactive,
                      ulSidenavClass: 'block-display height-adjust'
                  }
              } else {
                  return {
                      ...name,
                      menuClicked: 'active,
                      ulSidenavClass: 'block-display'
                  }
              }

           } else {
                 return {
                      ...name,
                      menuClicked: 'inactive,
                      ulSidenavClass: 'block-display height-adjust'
                  }
            }
    })}))

}
```

Comment: Happy to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your global state instead off the state of the specific object, what would help is mapping over the menu's setting them and just appending the new menu to the state.

You are setting on this.state instead off your this.state.desiredItem

Feel free to ask questions, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You must handle this in another way. The following `handleClick` function should solve your issue:

```
handleClick(menuClicked) {
  let menuStateDup = this.state.menuState.slice();
  let itemToUpdate = menuStateDup.find((element) => (
    element.menuName === menuClicked
  ));
  if ( itemToUpdate.menuClicked === 'active' ) {
    itemToUpdate.menuClicked = 'inactive';
    itemToUpdate.ulSidenavClass = 'block-display height-adjust';
  } else {
    // do vice-versa
  }
  this.setState({
    menuState: menuStateDup
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This should work except I need to map through all the menustate item not only the one user clicked. so I think if I change find to map this should work for me.  :-)